# Disable auto reconnect for remote client connections in mysql

Tags: mysql, remote, mysql5, reconnect

I use below version of MYSQL in my DB server.

```
root@XXXXXX-test-server:~# mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.16, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
root@XXXXX-test-server:~#
```

When I close remote connections from server side using KILL command, it is reconnectiong from client side automatically.

Server side:

```
mysql> 
mysql> show processlist;
+----+-----------+----------------------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id | User      | Host                 | db   | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+----+-----------+----------------------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 37 | test_user | 192.168.47.130:45042 | NULL | Sleep   |   75 |       | NULL             |
| 39 | root      | localhost            | NULL | Query   |    0 | init  | show processlist |
+----+-----------+----------------------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> kill 37;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> show processlist;
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 39 | root | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | init  | show processlist |
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Client Side:

```
mysql> 
mysql> show databases;
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    40
Current database: *** NONE ***

+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

How do I can disable auto reconnect option for remote connections?

I have tried with adding "reconnect=false" to '[client]' section in my.cnf config file. But it does not work. Still it reconnects from client side automatically.

Comment: What do you see at OS level? add process level details to the question from server and client side.